# Elastic Search with special character

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with elasticsearch. For example, I'm doing a character search. Think of it as a medicine name. We can easily find the medicine called A-ferin. However, what we call aferin, we need to be able to find it directly without any special characters.

What kind of research should I do to achieve this with .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom analyzer while indexing this particular field, while defining analyzer use char_filters of mapping type to replace the special character.

GET /_analyze

```
{
 "tokenizer": "keyword",
 "filter": [
        "asciifolding",
        "lowercase"
  ],
  "char_filter": [
    {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [
        "- => "

      ]
    }
  ],
  "text": "A-ferin"
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "aferin",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

For an exact matches, you can create keywords as subfields.

Comment: Thank you good solution. But we can use nest library so this solution is not enough for our problem.